# To you vs for you

Tags: usage

I want to know the correct usage "for you" vs "to you" for example:

> Congratulations for you too.
>   Congratulations to you too.

Which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatically correct way to say it is **"Congratulations to you too."**

English prepositions are very difficult to learn, because there are not a lot of rules and you mostly just have to learn every case separately.  In general, if you can imagine yourself "sending" feelings like congratulations or thanks, the appropriate preposition is **to**.

But we also say

> I am thinking **of** you (or **about** you)
>   I have great hopes **for** you
>   I have great faith **in** you
>   I wish you the best of luck (no preposition!)

So as you can see a lot of it depends on the exact sentence you use.  In the case of "congratulations", it's always *to*.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is the correct one. Here are some more examples:

> Congratulations to you!
>
> Congratulations on winning the competition!
>
> Congratulations to you both for winning the competition!

Comment: I would add a case where "for" is correct: congratulations are in order for you.